# Invalid factor level, NA generated when rbind

Tags: r

I need to add a new row/vector (NA,VC,1.5) to ToothGrowth, what I am doing wrong? (NA,"VC",1.5) not working..

```
str(ToothGrowth)
'data.frame':   60 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ len : num  4.2 11.5 7.3 5.8 6.4 10 11.2 11.2 5.2 7 ...
 $ supp: Factor w/ 2 levels "OJ","VC": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ dose: num  0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 ...

vast=rbind(ToothGrowth, c(NA,2,1.5))
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 2) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: You need a dataframe to `rbind` to a dataframe. Try `rbind(df, setNames(data.frame(NA, 2, 1.5), names(df)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
vast <- rbind(ToothGrowth, c(NA,"VC",1.5))
```

or

```
vast <- rbind(ToothGrowth, c(NA,levels(ToothGrowth$supp)[2],1.5))
```

The problem is the second value. One might think that R can map the integer to the factor level, but it does not. One of the many peculiarities of R.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to assign NA to column len or supp? I believe you are trying to assign NA to supp. In that case, the order of values is wrong. This will work for you depending on what you want:

```
rbind(ToothGrowth, c(len=2,supp=NA,dose=1.5))
```

Result:

```
61  2.0 <NA>  1.5
```